# Aligning images in the wp editor not working. How do i get this to work in custom theme?

Tags: posts, theme-development, images

I have this problem in my custom theme for the posts I want to be able to just add images in to the posts using the WordPress editor. I can do this but the problem that happens is that the WordPress editor will align the image in the editor but when i update the post then check the front end of the site the image does not align to where i have it in the editor.

So from my research so far i know that i can add a thumbnail image and a larger image to display in a post from using the feature image, and display it in my single.php page. I do use the feature image for my blog page that i have on index.php and that works fine.

I want to be able to add the images to the post via wordpress editor and the align image work so then when i hand off to the client they can easily add the images and align them easily.

Is my problem because i need to add something to my functions.php page to make adding images to the post that way dynamic? I was looking at the  wp_get_attachment_image() function. was not 100% sure how to implement this or if it will even fix my issue.

The only other thought i had was is there a pacific page dimension that single.php needs to be and that may be effecting the align image tool in WordPress editor, but then i don't think that is the case as all the text displays no problem.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Does your theme define styles for `.aligncenter`, `.alignright` etc? See: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/media/images/#alignments

Comment: Thanks I been on that page briefly before and many others trying to sort this out :) but didn't realize I needed define the styles for that.  Thanks you so much for the help Jacob Peattie much appreciated, all sorted now.